# How to select nodes with longest text with xpath?

Tags: xpath, lxml

I am trying to query for anchor with longest text by below:

```
//a[not(string-length(.) < ancestor::li//a/string-length(.))]
```

Seems it works in xpath 2.0 but not works in python lxml.

I am not very sure about this. Can anyone help explain in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: You should post the relevant code you have tried, along with the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath 2.0 expression actually finds all the `a` elements that are longer than any other `a` element within the same `li`; it will not select any `a` elements that are not within an `li`.

A better XPath 2.0 solution might be

```
for $m in max(//a/string-length()) return //a[string-length(.)=$m]
```

I don't think it can be done in XPath 1.0.

Comment: Ok, does python lxml support XPath 2.0?

Comment: You could try using the Saxon/C library which supports XPath 3.1. But it's a lot of effort unless you're going to use it more widely in your application.